# Jasper Report column break with group by

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a Jasper report using iReport 5.1.0 output to pdf. 
I have made report based on group by clause.
The group starts from 1st page itself but I want that to start from 2nd page so that i can show, page header, footer and title(without any content but an empty frame). How to do that?
I used a column break but that skips detail band also so not working.
Also, please tell if and how to set background for report.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the breaks, 
You need to use the **Page Break** instead of **Column Break** just **before** the **Group header**, so that every single group starts from the new page. And even the first page can be blank as per your requirement.

Or what can be a better option is , 
You can click on the **Group header** node in the **Report Inspector** and there you can see a **property** called **Start on a new Pag**e so if you **check** this property you can see that all your groups automatically start on a new page.

For setting the **background** of the report you can see the node called **Background** in the **report inspector**.
You can just navigate to that node give the height of the Background band and there you can add the **image element** from the palette and **assign** **the** **image** to be displayed in the background to the image element.

Hope that this helps
Thanks

Comment: Thank you Ankur for the solution. Thanks a lot.